# Show that if A is an NxN matrix whose ith row is the same as the ith row of the identity matrix then 1 is an eigenvalue of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that if A is an NxN matrix whose ith row is the same as the ith row of the identity matrix then 1 is an eigenvalue of A. I cannot figure out how to do this, I have plugged in values to a calculator and it appears that this is a always true.

For example
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
a & b & c\\
d & e & f
\end{bmatrix}$$
where a-f are any value. So 1 will be an eigenvalue of A.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A-I$ has an all-zero row, so is singular and has a non-trivial kernel. For any non-zero $v\in\operatorname{ker}(A-I)$, we have $(A-I)v=0$, which is to say to  $Av=v$, i.e., $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an eigenvector $\vec{v} = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$, so that $A\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}$. Then $\sum_{j = 1}^n A_{ij} v_j = \lambda v_i$. But since $A_{i\dot{}}$ is the $i$th row of the identity matrix, $A_{ij} = 0$ for $i \neq j$ and $A_{ii} = 1$. So the sum collapses to $v_i = \lambda v_i$, implying that either $\lambda = 1$ or $v_i = 0$. Then all you have to do is show that there must be at least one such eigenvector with a non-zero $i$th term.